# How can I load a script on every page except one?

Tags: php, html

Hi so I want to ask if it is possible to load a script on every page (by foe example placing it in the footer) except one (for example http://domain.com/tos.html)

To demonstrate you could use this G Analytics code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js'      type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
try{
var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-xxxxxx-x");
pageTracker._trackPageview();
} catch(err) {}
</script>
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(window.location.href!="http://domain.com/tos.html"){
    try{
        var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-xxxxxx-x");
        pageTracker._trackPageview();
    } catch(err) {}
}
```

You can use regular expression on the condition line.

```
if(window.location.href.match(/^http\:\/\/domain\.com\/tos\.html/)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! Now I have one more quesion: would this methode also work if the whole script (including if(window.location.href.match(/^http\:\/\/domain\.com\/tos\.html/)
) is located on a different server and and is called up through some sort of href/scr method?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't place the code in the footer and use [`REQUEST_URI`](http://php.net/manual/fr/reserved.variables.server.php) to identify the page you don't want to include it.

example:

```
<?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != '/tos.html'): ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js'      type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
try{
var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-xxxxxx-x");
pageTracker._trackPageview();
} catch(err) {}
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! Now I have one more quesion: would this methode also work if the hole script (including REQUEST_URI) is located on a different server and and is called up through some sort of href/scr method?